# RE: Executing Selenium RC script for Google Chrome on a Windows VM

Tags: java, selenium, junit4

I have a Windows 7 VM. I am trying to executing my selenium RC script on it. I am facing a problem. When I launch the simple basic script(Say 'log in'), it launches the chrome browser. Its keeps on saying 'loading...'.

After few mins, I get following error in eclipse console.

```
12:54:31.183 INFO - Launching Google Chrome...
12:54:36.791 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:49408
12:54:37.111 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:49412
12:54:37.379 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:49415
12:54:40.887 INFO - Couldn't proxy to http://hipaamg/ because host not found

12:55:01.770 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:49449
12:55:31.762 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:49462
13:24:33.733 ERROR - Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all session data
org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: timed out waiting for window 'null' to appear
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.waitForLoad(FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.java:578)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.waitForLoad(FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.java:537)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.createNewRemoteSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:375)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.getNewBrowserSession(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:811)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.doCommand(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:437)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handleCommandRequest(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:407)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handle(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:151)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
13:24:33.735 INFO - Killing Google Chrome...
13:24:33.846 INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser on session null
```

Could you please help me as to why am I getting this error. I have tried couple of things like disabling security. But I am not able to resolve this. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you noticed `Couldn't proxy to http://hipaamg/ because host not found` in your log? Fix that proxy problem by either removing the proxy or setting the right hostname.

Comment: Hi TIdusJar, I am able to launch n execute scripts on my local machine. But if I try to do execute same thing on a VM, this issue occurs.